# Scala - reduce function

Tags: scala, mapreduce, word-count

How to use reduce function in Scala? Is there a built in function like that?
I have implemented a program to find word count in scala.

```
object count {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val fruits = List("apple", "apple", "orange", "apple", "mango", "orange")
        val word = fruits.flatMap(_.split("\n"))
        val Map = word.map(word => (word,1)).groupBy(_._1)
        val reduce = Map.map(word => (word._1,word._2.foldLeft(0)((sum,c) => sum+ c._2)))
        println(reduce)     }}
```

How to replace foldleft with reduce function?

Comment: There is a `reduce`, but `foldLeft` is more appropriate in this case, as `reduce` doesn't accept a default value, so it would fail on an empty list.

Comment: If we use reduce instead how will the function look like?

Comment: i just upvoted this.  in the current state however, it needs improvement in the way its phrased... but still i think this question has some pedagogical value, and is useful to intermediate/begginer scala users

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Entire example above should be implemented like this

```
fruits groupBy(word => word) mapValues(_.size)
```

or like this as replacement for fold

```
val reduce = Map.map(word => (word._1,word._2.size))
```

but if you absolutely positively must use reduce in the same exact code, it would be something like this

```
val reduce = Map.map(word => (word._1,word._2.map(_=>1).reduce(_+_)))
```

Comment: Cool example. For me using Scala version 2.11.4, the second statement gets an error, but this works: fruits groupBy(word => word) map(word => (word._1,word._2.size))

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Btw, instead of using (word => word), (identity) may also be used when parameter and return value are the same.

Answer (score 2):

your example can be done simpler as follows:

```
> fruits.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size) 
res176: Map[String, Int] = Map("mango" -> 1, "orange" -> 2, "apple" -> 3)
```

however, reduce is useful here if you want to parallelize and use the MapReduce pattern. If you don't parallelize, you would just sequentially reduce lists of ones (1,1,1,1...). Compare:

```
> List(1,1,1,1,1,1,1).reduce{(a,b) => println(s"$a+$b=${a+b}"); a + b} 
1+1=2
2+1=3
3+1=4
4+1=5
5+1=6
6+1=7
res187: Int = 7
```

with the parallelized version (note the `par` method):

```
> List(1,1,1,1,1,1,1).par.reduce{(a,b) => println(s"$a+$b=${a+b}"); a + b} 
1+1=2
1+1=2
1+2=3
1+1=2
2+2=4
3+4=7
res188: Int = 7
```

you can use the MapReduce pattern in your case by defining the commonly used `reduceByKey` function as follows:

```
implicit class MapReduceTraversable[T, N](val traversable: Traversable[(T, N)]) {
  def reduceByKey(f: (N, N) => N) = traversable.par.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).mapValues(_.reduce(f))
}

val fruits = List("apple", "apple", "orange", "apple", "mango", "orange", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple") 

fruits.map(f => (f,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

res2: collection.parallel.ParMap[String, Int] = ParMap(orange -> 2, mango -> 1, apple -> 7)
```

you can debug it as before:

```
fruits.map(f => (f,1)).reduceByKey{(a,b) => println(s"$a+$b=${a+b}"); a + b} 

1+1=2
1+1=2
2+1=3
3+1=4
4+1=5
5+1=6
6+1=7
res9: Map[String, Int] = Map("mango" -> 1, "orange" -> 2, "apple" -> 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in function which behaves like that. You can use `mapValues` instead of second `map` to simplify it a bit, but there is no similar `foldValues`.